How do I fix a stuck low-feerate transaction that was sweeping the wallet?
My friend is using BlueWallet. They created a 1-input-1-output transaction that sends all their funds, but used a feerate of 1.7 s/vB. The transaction has been subsequently stuck for a couple weeks, because no blocks have been including any transactions with feerates of less than 2 s/vB. I’m trying to advise them, but not intimately familiar with BlueWallet.
We considered using the RBF feature, but it doesn’t show up for this transaction. (Maybe because no other funds are left?)
I read that there is a "Cancel Transaction" feature, which I think will create a RBF transaction that sends the funds back to their own wallet. I guess that it should work, but they’ll have to pay two higher transaction fees in that case. I also considered sending a small payment to the wallet to provide funds for RBFing the original transaction, but then I’ll pay additional fees and they probably would not end up with an empty wallet. We do not control the receiving end, so we cannot CPFP the transaction.
The optimal mitigation would simply replace the original transaction with another 1-input-1-output sweep transaction that pays a sufficiently higher feerate.
Is there maybe a way to just "forget" a transaction with BlueWallet in order for them to be able to make a higher feerate sweep transaction? Is there some special-casing for transactions that empty a wallet that can be found in some advanced options menu? Would resyncing the wallet perhaps make the wallet software forget about this transaction? Do you have any other suggestions how to easily and/or cost-effectively create the replacement tranasaction or otherwise get out of this situation?
